# MySQL getting DISTINCT ID when joining a table with itself

Tags: mysql

I was trying to teach myself something new and having a look at the way WordPress structures it's tables to work with revisions.

The structure is (sorta) as follows:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
| ID | post_title |      post_date      | post_name  |   post_content  | post_parent |
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Foo        | 2012-09-20 10:00:00 | Foo        | Bar             |           0 |
|  2 | Arrrrr     | 2012-09-20 10:05:00 | Arrrr      | Pirates!        |           0 |
|  3 | Arrrrrr    | 2012-09-20 10:06:00 | revision-1 | Argh pirates    |           2 |
|  4 | Arrrrrr    | 2012-09-20 10:06:00 | revision-2 | Argh piratessss |           2 |
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Now, I'd like to make a query that gives me ONLY the parent rows (Foo and Arrrr) with their ID's, BUT with their revised content.

I came up with following query:

```
SELECT original.ID, revision.post_title, revision.post_content, revision.post_name FROM wp_posts AS original
INNER JOIN wp_posts AS revision ON original.ID = revision.post_parent
WHERE original.post_status = 'publish'
AND original.post_parent = 0
ORDER BY original.ID, revision.ID DESC
```

This gives me following result:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
| ID | post_title |      post_date      | post_name  |   post_content  | post_parent |
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Foo        | 2012-09-20 10:00:00 | Foo        | Bar             |           0 |
|  2 | Arrrrrr    | 2012-09-20 10:06:00 | revision-2 | Argh piratessss |           2 |
|  2 | Arrrrrr    | 2012-09-20 10:06:00 | revision-1 | Argh pirates    |           2 |
|  2 | Arrrrr     | 2012-09-20 10:05:00 | Arrrr      | Pirates!        |           0 |
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

But I'd like to further reduce it to:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
| ID | post_title |      post_date      | post_name  |   post_content  | post_parent |
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Foo        | 2012-09-20 10:00:00 | Foo        | Bar             |           0 |
|  2 | Arrrrrr    | 2012-09-20 10:06:00 | revision-2 | Argh piratessss |           2 |
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

I've tried adding `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT`, and adding `GROUP BY original.ID` but both didn't give me the desired result.

Comment: Assuming ID is autoincrement you should be ordering your posts by `ORDER BY original.ID, inherit.ID` instead of `ORDER BY original.post_date, inherit.post_date DESC`  
And, to me, renaming the second table (alias) to `revision` makes more sense

Comment: I've changed the query as you said, you're right that revision makes more sense. I see no difference in using the post_date or the ID, they're both as fast...

Comment: Using IDs is not about speed, but about correct sequence: you have 2 revisions with the same date, but they will have different IDs.  
Are you trying to get one latest revision for each post? Then group by original.ID to get MAX(inherit.ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't distinguish different revisions of one topic for each other except date you can do the following:

```
select * from wp_posts p join
                (
                    select max(post_date) as max_dtm, id
                    from wp_posts
                    group by if(post_parent = 0, id, post_parent)
                ) v on p.id = v.id and p.post_date = v.max_dtm;
```